# Determine what JAVA-EE application module called intercepted method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, module, ejb-3.0, interceptor

Lets say we have a few modules in our application:

`REST API`

`WEB`

`CORE`

`DAO`

For all methods in `CORE` we have EJB @Interceptor defined. Is it possible to determine what `module` is calling method in `CORE`?

Example: I have a method `CORE.methodThatHasInterceptor()`

Than I call it from `WEB.unknownMethod(){ CORE.methodThatHasInterceptor() }`

It goes to interceptor of `methodThatHasInterceptor` method:

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object interceptor(InvocationContext invocCtx) throws Exception { 
// is it possible to know that it was called from WEB.unknownMethod() ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of InvocationContext is quite informative on that subject:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html

I'll quote the example code right at the top:

```
    @AroundInvoke
public Object logInvocation(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
   String class = ctx.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName();
   String method = ctx.getMethod().getName();
   Logger.global.entering(class, method, ctx.getParameters());
   try {
      Object result = ctx.proceed();
      Logger.global.exiting(class, method, result);
      return result;
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      Logger.global.throwing(class, method, e);
      throw e;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is how to determine information of method that being called. I want to know information about method that called  method that has interceptor.

Comment: I don't get that one. That will be a method of a class of your JEE container, a class dealing with EJB invocations. Probably it will always be the same one too.